# How can I overlay two plots with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to superimpose the two plots, which I attach. That is, to put the two lines on the same plot.
I provide the subset of data, so that the graphs can be reproduced.

I want to superimpose the two plots, which I attach. That is, to put the two lines on the same plot. I provide the subset of data, so that the graphs can be reproduced.

```
    n = 100   
    r1 = runif(1,0.75,0.98)
    r3 = runif(1,0.4,0.7)
    r <- sample(c(r1, r1*-1, r3, r3*-1),1)
        mx <- runif(1, 1,10)
        my <- runif(1, 3,10)
        
        
        df = as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n=n, mu=c(mx, my), Sigma=matrix(c(1, r, r, 1), nrow=2), empirical=TRUE))
        colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("x", "y")
        
        b <- rtruncnorm(n=1, a=0, b=10, mean=4, sd=10)
        df$y <- df$y*b

lr = lm(df$x~df$y)$coeff
intercepto = -lr[1]/lr[2]
pendiente = 1/lr[2]
        
        lr_y <- round(lm(df$y~df$x)$coeff,2)
        if(lr_y[2]>=0){
          label_y = paste0("y = ",lr_y[1], " + ",lr_y[2],"x")
        }else{
          label_y = paste0("y = ",lr_y[1], " - ",abs(lr_y[2]),"x")
        }
        
        lr_x <- round(lm(df$x~df$y)$coeff,2)
        if(lr_x[2]>=0){
          label_x = paste0("x = ",lr_x[1], " + ",lr_x[2],"y")
        }else{
          label_x = paste0("x = ",lr_x[1], " - ",abs(lr_x[2]),"y")
        }
      
        
          
    p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
      geom_point(col = "blue")+
       geom_smooth( method='lm', formula= y~x, se = F, col = "black")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
            axis.title= element_text(size = 14),
            legend.position = "none")+
      labs(title = paste("Y sobre X: ",  label_y)) 
      
    
    
    p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = x))+
      geom_point(col = "blue")+
      geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y~x, se = F, col = "black")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
            axis.title= element_text(size = 14),
            legend.position = "none")+
      labs(title = paste("X sobre Y: ",  label_x))+
       coord_flip()

    p12 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
      geom_point(col = "blue")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
            axis.title= element_text(size = 14),
            legend.position = "none")+geom_abline(aes(slope = pendiente, intercept = intercepto), size = 1, col = "red")+geom_abline(aes(slope = lr_y[2], intercept = lr_y[1]), size = 1, col = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: please provide at least a subset of your data, so we can reproduce the plots. You can paste the output of `dput(df)`. If it is too large, use `dput(head(df, 20))`

Comment: You provided the sample size, not the actual subset of the data

Comment: The sample size is 100

Comment: Please just do as asked, and provide the code for the actual data.frame object, not the upstream processes, which are irrelevant to the question. use `dput(df)`

Comment: running upstream code may require loading additional packages and the likes. I do not recognize mvrorm, as an example

Comment: Doesn't geom_smooth solve your problem? I mean why do you create 2 different graphs? could you please give more detail? if there is no reason for this, I could provide a sample code but I'm not sure it's useful in your case...

Comment: How would you use geom_smooth to solve the problem?

Comment: @Amelia see my answer, I hope that works in your case...

Answer (score 0):

to plot two different regression lines on the same plot, I add two geom_smooth layers to the same plot but with different data or aesthetic mappings. simple example: I hope that also works in your case...

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100)
)

# Perform the regressions
lr_y <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
lr_x <- lm(x ~ y, data = df)

# Extract coefficients and create label strings
label_y <- sprintf("y = %.2f + %.2fx", coef(lr_y)[1], coef(lr_y)[2])
label_x <- sprintf("x = %.2f + %.2fy", coef(lr_x)[1], coef(lr_x)[2])

# Create a new data frame for the second line
df_line <- data.frame(
  y = df$y,
  predicted_x = predict(lr_x, newdata = df)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(col = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x, se = F, col = "black", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(data = df_line, aes(x = predicted_x, y = y), col = "red", linetype = "dashed") + # adjusted line
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = paste("Y sobre X: ", label_y, "\nX sobre Y: ", label_x))
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't the straight lines cut?

Comment: @Amelia I'm not sure I get what you mean by "cut". can you please extend your question a little bit more?

Comment: I mean that the regression lines intersect at a point (x,y).

Comment: @Amelia, if I understand correctly, you're seeking a visualization where the two regression lines (one for y on x and the other one for x on y) intersect, indicating a point of equivalence. sorry it's really hard to predict what you want without the desired output or original data.  I'll add another solution to ensure this by manually calculating the predicted values for the second model and plotting them accordingly... (Still not sure it's what you want tho)

Comment: As it appears in the codes I sent, I make sure that the straight lines cross. I simply wanted the two graphs I sent, each with a line, to be transformed into a single graph with the two lines in the same position they have in each individual graph. Thank you very much for your interest

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @AltunE, but with the method for data creation that you used. Keep in mind you are generating random numbers so your results may differ each time unless you save.

```
base::library(package = ggplot2)
base::library(package = MASS)
base::library(package = truncnorm)

n = 100   
r1 = runif(1,0.75,0.98)
r3 = runif(1,0.4,0.7)
r <- sample(c(r1, r1*-1, r3, r3*-1),1)
    mx <- runif(1, 1,10)
    my <- runif(1, 3,10)
    
    
    df = as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n=n, mu=c(mx, my), Sigma=matrix(c(1, r, r, 1), nrow=2), empirical=TRUE))
    colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("x", "y")
    
    b <- rtruncnorm(n=1, a=0, b=10, mean=4, sd=10)
    df$y <- df$y*b
    
    lr_y <- round(lm(df$y~df$x)$coeff,2)
    if(lr_y[2]>=0){
      label_y = paste0("y = ",lr_y[1], " + ",lr_y[2],"x")
    }else{
      label_y = paste0("y = ",lr_y[1], " - ",abs(lr_y[2]),"x")
    }
    
    lr_x <- round(lm(df$x~df$y)$coeff,2)
    if(lr_x[2]>=0){
      label_x = paste0("x = ",lr_x[1], " + ",lr_x[2],"y")
    }else{
      label_x = paste0("x = ",lr_x[1], " - ",abs(lr_x[2]),"y")
    }

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(col = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(
    method  ='lm', 
    formula = y ~ x, 
    se      = FALSE, 
    col     = "black"
  ) +
  geom_smooth(
    data    = df,
    mapping = aes(x = y, y = x),
    method  = "lm",
    formula = y ~ x, 
    se      = FALSE, 
    col     = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    strip.text      = element_text(size = 16),
    axis.title      = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  labs(title = paste("Y sobre X: ",  label_y)) 

print(plot)
```

Here is the result of one such run:
[image]

Comment: That's how it worked for me. But it doesn't make sense, because the two regression lines intersect at a point. Moreover, if you superimpose the two plots, the cut is obvious.